# Conditional regex for URL formatting

Tags: php, regex, url

Looking for an efficient regex to do this

`/url-example-123.shtml` **&** `/url-example-25.shtml`

**to** `/url-example-3`

**Objectives:**

1. remove the `.shtml`
2. replace with `3` if the numbers are between `25` and `125`

Comment: Which language are you using? It's not recommended to use only regex to check whether the number is within your bounds.

Comment: Where do you want to use this?

Comment: This is to add as regex option in to a wordpress Redirection plugin. It is PHP script.  The objective 1 is straightforward. I do not know the possibility of achieving Objective 2 with regex, So this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give a language I can only give you a regex. You can use the following to match numbers between 25 & 125: `(?:(?:1[0-1][0-9])|(?:12[0-5]))|(?:[^\d](?:2[5-9])|(?:[^\d](?:[3-9][0-9])))`. You can then just do a replace with that match and a 3. If there will always be a .shrml at the end then you could add that to the end of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague. Not sure what should happen if there is no number, or if the number is outside the given range. Now that you've specified PHP, I've edited my answer:

```
echo preg_replace(
  "/(?<=\/url-example-)(2[5-9]|[4-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-5]).shtml/",
  "3",
  myUrl);
```